# What is the age at which pensions are no longer taxed in Pennsylvania?

Tags: united-states, pension, pennsylvania

I have a pension from Lockheed Martin that I started receiving when I was 59. I am now 63, and they are still taking PA taxes out, even though, according to my understanding, the rule is that pension received after "normal retirement age" are not supposed to be taxed. I can't find any specific age that this might mean, and Lockheed hasn't been helpful in clarifying when they're going to stop withholding the state taxes.

Can anyone help me out with pension taxes in PA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pennsylvania*-qualified pensions (as well as IRA distributions after age 59.5, whether received as lump-sums or in smaller amounts) are not subject to Pennsylvania *state* income tax. See the [Pennsylvania Department of Revenue website](https://revenue-pa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/364/~/do-i-have-to-pay-pa-income-tax-on-my-retirement-pension-after-i-retire-from-the) for more details including age requirements etc.  Note that the Pennsylvania Department of Revenue cannot exempt income from *Federal* income tax; that is up to the US Congress to decide.

Whether your pension from Lockheed-Martin is qualified in Pennsylvania or not is something that you need to find out.  [The rules for being qualified](https://revenue-pa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/433/~/what-is-a-qualified-pension-program%3F) are not very onerous, and most pension plans would qualify but you never know. One point to keep in mind is the *source* of the pension which might make it taxable. For example, if your pension is paid by Lockheed-Martin's Maryland operations where you worked all your life while living in Pennsylvania just north of the Mason-Dixon Line, Pennsylvania might well tax your pension.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer! Lockheed wasn't able to tell me whether this pension was qualified or not - is there any other way of finding this out?

Comment: You might want to start with [What is a qualified pension program?](https://revenue-pa.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/433/~/what-is-a-qualified-pension-program%3F).

Comment: And does not taxable in Pennsylvania mean exempt from federal tax or just state tax?

Comment: @Eric it means exempt from state tax.  Pennsylvania has no power to exempt any source of income from federal tax.